# Executando JAR pelo Browser

Tags: java, firefox, google-chrome-extensão

Estou com dificuldades em entender como fazer:

## O que Desejo

Desejo criar uma extensão do Google Chrome/Firefox que quando eu aperte um botão no html da minha extensão, ele execute um arquivo .JAR passando por parâmetro configurações feita pelo usuário na extensão. Então pensei na utilização do JNLP.

## Problema

Porém pelo que entendi do JNLP ele executa o JAR diretamente do servidor, e oque eu realmente desejo é que ele execute um JAR na maquina do cliente esse JAR estará já em uma pasta dentro da própria extensão `minhaExtensao/lib/foo.jar`

## Duvida

Seria possível executar ele assim na maquina do cliente?

Comment: Creio que você está procurando sejam `Applets`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da uma olhada aqui http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Acredito que basta apenas criar como o exemplo abaixo no html do seu plugin.

```
<applet code=TicTacToe.class 
        archive="TicTacToe.jar"
        width=120 height=120>
        <param name="param1" value="value1">
        <param name="param2" value="value2">
</applet>
```

Faz o teste e posta o resultado aqui, vou tentar fazer um também.

Comment: Opa, vou tentar!

Comment: Um detalhe, o uso direto da tag `applet` não é mais recomendado (no HTML 5 a tag `applet` não é mais suportada, existem sintaxes alternativas com tags `object` e `embed`). A melhor maneira de distribuir um applet hoje em dia é através do [Deployment Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html), que, entre outras coisas, gera a tag correta para cada browser / doctype e verifica se o usuário possui uma versão compatível da JVM (sugerindo a instalação de uma versão do Java caso ela não seja encontrada).

Answer (score 2):

O [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html) não executa o código no servidor, ele é um protocolo feito exatamente para permitir a distribuição de aplicações para clientes (ou seja, entre outras funcionalidades, o JNLP permite que um cliente faça o download e execute uma aplicação localmente). Eu recomendo o tutorial oficial da Oracle sobre [Deploy de Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html), bem como o caminho [Deployment in-Depth](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/index.html). Pela descrição dos seus requisitos porém eu iria além de um Applet, acredito que você está procurando pelo [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html) e o famigerado botão [image: Botão de Lançamento] (que [pode ser substituído](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/changeLaunchButtonOfJWS.html) por qualquer outra imagem).

Comment: Então, mas eu quero que o cliente baixe e execute ele localmente. Pois esse software terá que usar os recursos do cliente.

Comment: @ralfting. É isso que o JNPL e o Web Start fazem. Eles instalam a aplicação no cliente, e conforme as permissões que você requisitar (assinando o código) pode ter acesso total aos recursos do cliente (sistemas de arquivo, rede, etc). O software não é executado no servidor e sim na máquina do cliente.